# Need to know how to type specific kanji found in image

Tags: simplified-characters, writing, characters

I am making a website for a friend. He has a (very) low quality logo for me to use. I want to remake the logo but it contains kanji. I do not know how to read kanji so I do not know how to remake these characters other than doing so by hand....

http://www.schneidi.com/images/logo%20-%20wun%20hop%20kuen%20do.jpg

What are the kanji characters in this image, how do I type them (or can you just type them for me and I copy/paste?) and what do they mean?

Thank you !!

Comment: In addition, "Wun Hop Kuen Do" is Cantonese, `混合拳道`; and "kajukenbo" is Japanese, `カジュ拳法` (Karate & Judo mixed kenpou).

Comment: If anything, it's 'hanzi', not 'kanji'.

Comment: @deutschZuid: you may know, 'kanji' is a Japanese pronunciation.

Comment: @Stan Not exactly. Kanji were originally Chinese characters borrowed into Japanese, but were later mutated to adapt to their own writing style. New characters were invented in the process as well. So drawing equivalence between the Hanzi and Kanji is not recommended. (By the way, I was commenting on the OP's use of the word, not your comment, hence the lack of @).

Comment: @deutschZuid: if the "own writing style" and "new characters invented" are considered as criteria of equivalence, the traditional and simplified Chinese characters can be considered as **two different kinds of hanzi** too (Taiwan and Hong Kong people do invent some character that are never used in mainland China. And even for some not simplified characters, strokes are not exactly the same). In similarity, kanji is in general quite similar to hanzi, and Chinese people are able to recognize most of them. So I think it's OK to say kanji and that wouldn't be ambiguous.

Comment: @deutschZuid: Yet it's interesting to research the borrowing words in English. Sometimes English borrows the Japanese pronunciation but not Chinese. Like `围棋`, i.e. [碁](http://www.zdic.net/zd/zi/ZdicE7ZdicA2Zdic81.htm) in ancient Chinese, it's [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) in formal English but not **Weiqi** or **Qi**. Certainly, as Chinese, I prefer `hanzi` being the formal English expression for those characters. But it just depends neither on Chinese nor on Japanese :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `功夫`. You might want to try figuring out further characters using handwriting input as on e.g. http://nciku.com

Comment: +1 useful link. If there's such a tool for seal scripts, it will be convenient for archaeologists.

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for tools to identify Chinese characters, you can look them up in a dictionary using radical + brushstroke count.

Here is an example of a dictionary that uses radicals: http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/sinograms.html?r

I'm not sure if there is a systematic method to identify which part of the character is the radical, but if you divide the character into separated "parts" it's usually the left-most or top-most part.

Comment: Yes this is the standard way that Chinese language users look up a character that they don't know how to pronounce. Unfortunately there is no standard way to figure out which is the radical. Most of the time you have to learn to recognise the radicals, or try the one with the least number of strokes.